Unresolved reference: tasks.jib.doLast in build.gradle.kts
I have old Kotlin project success build by build.gradle:
tasks.jib.doLast {}


But I need to change this to build.gradle.kts:
 plugins {
  kotlin("jvm")
  id("application")
  id("com.google.cloud.tools.jib")
}

group = "com.myproject"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

application {
    mainClass.set("MainKt")
}
dependencies {
  annotationProcessor("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc")
  annotationProcessor("com.github.blagerweij:liquibase-sessionlock")
  annotationProcessor("org.liquibase:liquibase-core:4.8.0")
  annotationProcessor("org.postgresql:postgresql")
}

kotlin {
  jvmToolchain {
    languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of("17"))
  }
}

jib {
  from.image = "amazoncorretto:17-alpine-jdk"
  to {
    image = "image"
    tags = setOf("$version")
  }
  container.user = "nobody"
}


tasks.jib.configure {
  dependsOn(provider {
    tasks.jibDockerBuild
  })
}

tasks.jib.doLast {
//some logic
}

and now I get error:
Line 32: doLast {
           ^ Unresolved reference: tasks.jib.doLast

Maybe shoul'd I use tasks.withType? But with this configuration it is not defined also
tasks.withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        jib.doLast { }
    }
}

Thank you for all your suggestions.

I know that "tasks" from "build.gradle.kts" file is in abstract class ProjectDelegate : Project
but "tasks" from "build.gradle" is in public interface Project extends Comparable, ExtensionAware, PluginAware

tasks gives you access to the TaskContainer, as you can see on getTasks() on the Project object (docs).getTasks() in Java becomes tasks in Kotlin

The Groovy code
tasks.jib.doLast {
  // someLogic
}

should be replaced in Kotlin with
tasks.jib.configure {
  doLast {
    // someLogic
  }
}

In fact, you can include that configuration in the previous configuration block as it's doing the same thing:
tasks.jib.configure {
  dependsOn(provider {
    tasks.jibDockerBuild
  })
  doLast {
    //some logic
  }
}

Note this difference is because in Kotlin DSL tasks.jib is a TaskProvider (via an auto-generated accessor because it was defined in a plugin) but in Groovy it's the jib Task object itself (via Groovy/Gradle magic by virtue of tasks being a NamedDomainObjectCollection.
I encourage you to click/hover on the objects in your build script; if you are using a suitable IDE this will tell you what type they are and lead you to what API is available for them.

Great :) If you could accept the answer when you get a moment it would be appreciated
